# How to terminate python script by C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I want to run some python script in my application, but sometimes I want to terminate the script before it finishes and then run some other python script.

I currently use `PyRun_SimpleString(python_script)` to run the script, but I don't know how to terminate it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: When do you want to stopthe script? How do you decide to stop it? Before calling PyRun_SimpleString  the script has not been started yet, and after calling PyRun_SimpleString it has already finished.

Comment: In my Application, select a python script file, and read it's content  ,and then call the  PyRun_SimpleString() to run it , But sometime,user can stop this script by press a button STOP to terminate the script  before it finishes,i don't know how to terminate it. If use the pytho  command line to run script ,we can use  CTRL+C  to break ,but how to use the python.dll  API to break it ,not find yet

Comment: @n.m. It's not guaranteed that all threads exits before PyRun_SimpleString is returned. Sometimes you have to wait till the python interpreter terminates all threads. I have observed this behavior in old XBMC source code python interface.

Comment: @Fent what you can try is raising PyExc_SystemExit which will achieve what you may want. But you may have to raise this exception for each thread if you're having many threads.

Comment: @Fent could your script run in a subprocess?

Comment: Do you want this in C because this can easily be done in Python?

Comment: `PyRun_SimpleString` is a synchronous function, So I assume only way to terminate would be to run it in a thread and abort the thread

Comment: @PulathisiBandara you were interested in this problem - have you seen the solution in this duplicate suggestion? (I think it's definitely worth keeping the answer on this question though)

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for attaching the duplicate. I saw some answers similar to the attached duplicate, but not complete like the attached one here, thanks. I agree with you the question is the same, though the answers are different in the approach.

Answer (score -1):

To kill a python script from your C program, you can find its process id, using the name of the python script(or some other regex), and then kill the process.

My C is a little rusty, but the code below will kill a running python  script called `test.py`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {
    bool kill_python = true;

    if (kill_python == true) {
        FILE *cmd = popen("kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[t]est.py' | awk '{print $2}')", "r");
        pclose(cmd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`ps aux | grep '[t]est.py' | awk '{print $2}'` returns the process id of the python script
`kill -9 {PID}` kills the process forcibly(`-9` = non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)

Comment: This answer itself doesn't solve the problem, But I have an idea going through this solution.
Please consider this to the question asked, which is not a 'python script' he wants to stop but a 'python script string' which currently doesn't have a PID. 
What he can do is fork a process, and once he wants to kill the python script, kill that forked process.
In that way, I think this is a good approach and hence awarding the bounty.

Comment: This answer is already given by  @georgexsh, sorry that I didn't notice earlier.